# Ссылка через код php

Tags: php, html

Ребята, проблема. Есть код, выводит картинки с ссылками. Вот он:

```
function getItem($title, $url, $img) { return '<div class="item">
           <div class="blogodel">
        <a href="'.trim($url).'" target="_blank">
          <img src="'.trim($img).'" alt=""><div class="desc"><strong>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</strong> Played: 95741236 times</div>
          '.trim($title).'
        </a>
      </div></div>'; }
```

Все работает отлично, но когда мне пришлось подключить аналитику, все перестает работать!
Пишу вот так:

```
function getItem($title, $url, $img) {
  return '<div class="item">

<div class="blogodel">
        <a href="'.trim($url).'" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Test1.Click', 'Click', 'Test1']);">
          <img src="'.trim($img).'" alt=""><div class="desc"><strong>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</strong> Played: 95741236 times</div>
          '.trim($title).'
        </a>
      </div></div>';
}
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_trackEvent' (T_STRING) in/home/username/site.ru/test/index.php on line 12
> ```

Помогите решить проблему! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Все, уже не надо, разобрался! Если что, то нужно экранировать апострофы!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Все, уже не надо, разобрался! Если что, то нужно экранировать апострофы!

Answer (score 4):

```
function getItem($title, $url, $img) {
  return '<div class="item">

<div class="blogodel">
        <a href="'.trim($url).'" onClick="_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Test1.Click", "Click", "Test1"]);">
          <img src="'.trim($img).'" alt=""><div class="desc"><strong>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</strong> Played: 95741236 times</div>
          '.trim($title).'
        </a>
      </div></div>';
}
```

Почитайте, как в php нужно ставить кавычки внутри кавычек. =) Я вместо одинарных поставил двойные. Еще, как вариант, их можно было экранировать.

Comment: А ещё можно было про хередок рассказать ).

Comment: Я верстальщик. пхп на уровне - верстать внутри него, и какие-то мелочь по нужде подпилить. так что, про хедерок я даже не вижу, что там можно лучше сделать =)